# Digital Color Meter does not show all pixels. Is there a tool that does?

Tags: screen, resolution, screen-capture, color

Digital Color Meter seems to drop pixels from the inspection window on retina displays. Here is what Digital Color Meter thinks the spotlight search icon looks like:

[image]

However, a screen capture PNG shows a much more detailed icon (zoomed up here to match the zoom level of Digital Color Meter):

[image]

The display on my macbook 13" has a native resolution of 2560x1600 but is scaled to 1440x900, so perhaps Digital Color Meter is dropping pixels to compensate for this. But I would like the meter to show actual pixels, like a screen capture shows. Is there a mode to do this? Is there an alternative tool?

*edit: this is Sierra 10.12.3*

Comment: What version of macOS?

Comment: This is on Sierra 10.12.3